# Getting Started With SourceForge

Tags: svn, web-hosting, issue-tracking, sourceforge

Hi I want to develop a C++ project with a few friends on a SVN integrated Issue Tracking system.

I almost got it working on sourceforge, i can check out the repository to a local folder but i cant commit anything up to the server. It says permission denied. Ive looked around but the permissions seems to be as they should. I'm the only admin account so I'm assuming that the admin can do everything by default. Help please!

I cant find any getting started guide on the sourgeforge homepage nor can i find a user forum. The whole homepage / system doesn't seem very friendly for newcomers like me. Should i try looking for a different hosting system?

Comment: You could try GitHub. I tried SF, but it was way too complicated for my tastes and GitHub provides everything I need in a nicer package.

Comment: hmm okay ill look into it, im used to SVN because ive used it at work and in school. I remember GIT being a pain whenever you needed to make merge though.

Comment: You can use `svn` with GitHub (it's sort of beta): https://github.com/blog/644-subversion-write-support

Comment: Git Hub is looking very good so far, very fast, clean and easy. i might as well try out git and make a proper opinion about it.

Comment: You can even set up Wiki pages and static HTML for your project. No PHP or things like that, but there *is* support for Markdown!

Answer (score 1):

1. Start with the [Site Documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/WikiStart) page.  It includes comprehensive documentation for the site.
2. Check out the [Subversion](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Subversion) documentation.

   Notice this quote:

> Once Subversion has been enabled, you will need to [grant access](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Subversion%20permissions%20management) before
> the repository may be written to.

Comment: cayou're right i absolutely want to grant access, looking at the svn-scm module it shows that the admin group has every permission has create

Answer (score -1):

First you should join team of the project to gain permission to commit. The best way to do it is to find interesting for you project on [help wanted page](http://sourceforge.net/people/)

Also it is possible to contact project owner directly. 
Good luck

Comment: hmm do i have to do this even if im the creator of the project?

Comment: i thought you are talking about joining existing project, never mind then